# how to get rid of scroll bar in facebook fan page

Tags: html, facebook, iframe

I recently created a fb page for sharing my photography work. I'm new to iframes n stuff so I did my welcome page via an app provided by wildfire

Here is the link to the page https://www.facebook.com/pages/Bharath-Keshav-Photography/144046682351773

Now, how  exactly do i get rid of the vertical scroll? The app specifically says that scripts aren't allowed. Also, setting body style="overflow: hidden" isn't allowed as tells me that the body tag can't be used

Comment: It looks fine in Firefox 6. No vertical scrollbar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best solution would be to use the JS-SDK.
You can either use FB.Canvas.SetAutoResize to have your page automatically resized or, if you know exactly what the height and width of the page will be, use Fb.Canvas.SetSize

You can find more info here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/

Also, keep in mind that the maximum width of a page app is 520 pixels and from personal experience, it's best to keep it around 500-510px

Answer (score 0):

You have to make your css in this way

```
body {
            width:520px;
            margin:0;
            padding:0;
            border:0;
            overflow:hidden;
            }
```

and use FB.Canvas.setAutoResize();
In this way you can do your tab 520 pixel without scrollbar